# JVM hang, unable to print stack information

Tags: service, jvm, deadlock, jstack, jcmd

One of my services is deadlocked, I can't print the stack information. Is there any way to troubleshoot the problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run with `sudo`?

Comment: @JurajMartinka I tried

Comment: You could try `kill -3 PID` to get the threads stacks printed on the process' stdout: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178